# I don't know how to install ThreeJSExporter.ms

Tags: three.js

I have no idea where I should place this script or how I should execute it?

My end goal is to be able to export 3ds files directly to JSON to be imported into threejs.

I'm a noob with 3ds so please forgive my ignorance.

[link to the script](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/max/ThreeJSExporter.ms)

Comment: You might want to read this: http://bkcore.com/blog/3d/webgl-three-js-workflow-tips.html

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I thought the object conversion method was dated and using the script above was the recommended approach.  I have successfully loaded objects before, but I've had a heck of a time getting the mesh to look just right.  I'm sure it's just me being new to both three.js and 3dsmax & blender.   Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would follow the advice of WestLangley but for any Googlers that come across this and want to know what to do with a .ms script you need to run this from the command line from the directory where your autodesk 3ds max is installed.

```
3dsmax -U MAXScript your_script_name.ms
```